# If-Else program for days of the week

Tags: java

I need help with homework. I need to write a program that will use if else statements instead of the switch statement shown:

```
switch (day) {
case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
    message = "regular workday";
    break;
case 6: case 7:
    message = "weekend";
    break;
default:
    message = "tgif";
}
```

I need to allow the user to key in the day of the week and then display the corresponding output. I also need to make sure it tests the input for a valid number (1-7). The user needs to be able to enter as many different days as they would like and to have a value (-1) end the program when entered.

I have this so far:

```
public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int day;

        do {
            System.out.println("What day of the week do you want to enter? When finished, please enter \"-1\".");
            day = input.nextInt(); //User input assigned to variable day

            if (day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4) {
                System.out.println("Regular workday");
            }

            else if (day == 6 || day == 7) {
                System.out.println("Weekend");
            }

            else if (day == 5) {
                System.out.println("TGIF"); 
            }   

            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Month. Please try again or enter \"-1\" when finished.");
            }
        } //end do
        while (day != -1); //Loops when input meets the criteria
    }

}
```

PROBLEM: The problem I am having is that when I enter -1 to end the program, it takes it as an else and prints the else statement when I simply just want the program to end.

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code you have? Are you getting an error? Incorrect output?

Comment: Yes, do tell us what is wrong. Also fix the part that says "Invalid Month". :)

Comment: You've not explained the problem with the code you've posted or asked a question. Please [edit] to fix those things. Thanks.

Comment: @Blorgbeard When i input the -1 it doesnt close the program without saying the else statement. How can I get it to end without the else statement?

Comment: @KenWhite I have added the problem. my apologies

Comment: Try replace `else` with an `else if` and include a condition which will evaluate to false when the input is -1.

Comment: Turns out -1 actually isn't 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or even 7!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/3524982)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the line `else {` with `else if (day != -1) {`. This will trigger the branch for any number that didn't satisfy the previous conditions, or being -1

Answer (score 0):

You can re-test your input while inside the else-block and return false and/or jump to quitProgram-part - before showing the error message.